# Is this SQL construction prone to SQL Injection?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

**Note**: any SQL backend is fine for examples (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres), though for my examples I'm using MySQL to test.

---

I was wondering if the following construction is prone to SQL injection:

```
SELECT
    field1,
    field2,
    %s
FROM
    tbl
```

And the user can enter in a raw string there. I am fine with allowing bad input, but want to see if the user can do anything harmful with this, provided I remove certain characters, such as `;`. So if the user tried to do:

```
SQL % ('DROP TABLE users; ')
```

The SQL would just turn into invalid sql but not necessarily malicious:

```
SELECT
    field1,
    field2,
    DROP TABLE users
FROM
    tbl
```

But given a genius user capable of composing any string here, would the above be safe to malicious SQL injection, and if not, what might be an example string here that would be used to do so?

Comment: "...And the user can enter in a raw string there..." -- Yes, that's vulnerable to SQL Injection by definition.

Comment: Malicious injection. Could you show an example please?

Comment: Each engine has it's features and bugs. You won't probably be able to easily find a "hole" in the query, but rest assured that hackers will.

Comment: For example, a hacker could include the URL of their fake web site using XSS, and your app will show it. A naive user will think it's a link you are providing and will click on it. Once on the hacker's site they can ask the naive user to provide credentials, credit cards, bank accounts, etc.

Comment: You should not only be concerned with malicious SQL injection. Your app should protect users from well-intentioned input that causes your application to be faulty. Just as you would want to allow someone whose name is "O'Reilly" to enter their name on your site without causing an error.

Comment: But to answer your question, yes, there are ways that malicious users could cause mischief. They can't drop a table from a SELECT statement, but they could read data from other tables that they normally aren't authorized to read. Or they could execute a query so expensive that it would cause denial of service to other users. I'm not going to show details of how to do this.

Comment: How about `0; DROP TABLE Users; SELECT 1` or `(SELECT passwordHash FROM Users WHERE Admin = 1)`

Comment: @Charlieface I see. Yea, selecting data from other tables and/or constructing  statement that becomes so expensive it disrupts service can both be done and are quite malicious, even if a drop table won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your case is to never assemble a SQL statement with a string that comes from outside the backend layer. Therefore, do it with a string that is stored **inside** the backend.

For example, if there are 20 columns the user can choose from in the UI, then receive a number from 1 to 20 and then you can create an `IF/ELSE` sequence that will append the corresponding column for each number.

That way the parameter that is coming from outside won't ever be assembled in the SQL statement, but will be *used* to assemble the SQL query.